# What does $f$ is measurable as a function $f^{-1}(\mathbb{R})\to\mathbb{R}$ mean?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, terminology

I saw a question where we have $\overline{\mathbb{R}}:=\mathbb{R}\cup\{\pm\infty\}$
and $(X,S)$ is a measurable space, $f:\, X\to\overline{\mathbb{R}}$

In one part I was told to assume that $f$ is measurable as a function
$f^{-1}(\mathbb{R})\to\mathbb{R}$

What does it mean ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $Y=f^{-1}(\mathbb R)$ is a subset of $X$ and that $T=\{A\cap Y\mid A\in S\}$ is a sigma-algebra on $Y$. The question is to determine whether the function $g:Y\to\mathbb R$ defined by $g(x)=f(x)$ for every $x$ in $Y$, is measurable or not, seen as a function from the measurable space $(Y,T)$ to the measurable space $(\mathbb R,\mathcal B(\mathbb R))$.